# how to correctly sort labels on axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a waterfall chart using `ggplot2`. My data:

```
> PctCtr
   Index Volatility sign id        end      start
1    WMT 0.04894867  pos  1 0.04894867 0.00000000
2    MMM 0.09225684  pos  2 0.14120551 0.04894867
3    AIG 0.18997607  pos  3 0.33118159 0.14120551
4   AAPL 0.11067473  pos  4 0.44185632 0.33118159
5     KO 0.05972203  pos  5 0.50157835 0.44185632
6   COST 0.06088945  pos  6 0.56246780 0.50157835
7      C 0.16428627  pos  7 0.72675407 0.56246780
8   AMZN 0.12803944  pos  8 0.85479351 0.72675407
9    ICE 0.09104894  pos  9 0.94584245 0.85479351
10   VTR 0.05415755  pos 10 1.00000000 0.94584245
11 Total 1.00000000  pos 11 0.00000000 1.00000000
```

And my code:

```
GF = ggplot(PctCtr, aes(Volatility, fill = sign)) + 
  geom_rect(aes(Index,
                xmin = id - 0.475,
                xmax = id + 0.475,
                ymin = end,
                ymax = start)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)     
  scale_x_discrete("", breaks = levels(PctCtr$Index), labels = levels(PctCtr$Index))

GF
```

The resulting chart:
[image]

As you can see, the names on x-axis are messed up. I think it is because of `levels()` function as when I look at it, it returns alphabetically sorted values:

```
> levels(PctCtr$Index)
 [1] "AAPL"  "AIG"   "AMZN"  "C"     "COST"  "ICE"   "KO"    "MMM"   "Total"
[10] "VTR"   "WMT"
```

Please help me fix this. Thanks.

Comment: Please help me understand why this question is downvoted multiple times.

Comment: Because the question does not explain clearly what should be the index, one has to guess it is the one listed in the Index column also the script does not work if run in full. Have you tested it?

Comment: what do you mean by does not explain what should be?

Comment: Do you state anywhere what's the Index you want to plot? You just say it should no be alphabetical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just factor and change the levels of the Index column before the plot

```
PctCtr$Index <- factor(PctCtr$Index, levels=unique(PctCtr[,"Index"]))
```